# Firebase Function Failed to load function definition from source error Solution

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/firestore' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/macbook/Desktop/ein-itin-firebase-functions/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/package.json

Answer (score 8):

My Solution is change the

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/lib/firestore";
```

to

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
```

Answer (score 1):

## Check your log

Open the following file and you can see the specific error that caused this

`firebase-debug.log`

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you're using the `functions` key word, you must also import the proper library:

Example:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

then import `const functions = require("firebase-functions");`