# lib/logger/compat is not defined

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

After updating my Firebase dependencies (need new features) i've been trying to deploy them without success.

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

Before the update everything worked fine. Here is the Firebase documentation page for logging.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs#custom-logs

```
require("firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat");
```

Now the logging fails and i cant understand why.

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/logger/compat' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/admin/Desktop/Xxxxxxx Xcode/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/package.json
```

I've tried to delete and reinstall. Current versions are now.

```
Node = v16.18.0  
firebase tools = 11.15.0
```

What could i be missing?

Comment: try reinstalling the firebase-tool package `npm install -g firebase-tools`.Also check the suggestions in this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406512/firebase-function-failed-to-load-function-definition-from-source-error-solution) &[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225579/firebase-cloud-error-failed-to-load-function-definition-from-source)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it.

maybe you use `firebase-functions@v4.0.1(latest)` now.

from version 4, we can use

```
require("firebase-functions/logger/compat");
```

Edit like this, it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue.

I imported the logger like this before:

```js
import {log} from 'firebase-functions/lib/logger'
```

switching it to the following solved the issue for me:

```js
import {log} from 'firebase-functions/logger'
```